# Sum from multiply sheet and put the total amount in master or 1st sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have created but don't know what to add a code to put the total amount of all multiply sheet in the master or 1st sheet "A1" please help I'm newcomer please help if there is better code please tell me

```
Sub sum()

Dim i As Integer

Dim ws_num As Integer
Dim ws As Workbook
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim sumrg As Range


For Each sh In Sheets
If sh.Name <> "coverletter" Then
ws_num = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

For i = 1 To ws_num
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Activate
Set sumrg = ActiveSheet.Range("C5:D14")
Range("H4").Value = WorksheetFunction.sum(sumrg)
Next i
End If
Next


End Sub
```

Comment: please help me i don't know what to add after the `Set sumrg = ActiveSheet.Range("C5:D14")` to show all total amount of multiply sheet in the master sheet

Comment: So far, you have failed to explain where to put the sums. A good idea would be if the master worksheet had headers e.g. `A1: Name`, `B1: Sum`. Then you could write the names of the other worksheets in column `A` starting with cell `A2` and the sums to the corresponding cells of column `B` starting with cell `B2`. Please share your idea. Also, clarify if the sum of the range of each worksheet has to be written additionally to cell `H4` of each worksheet. You can [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73303317/edit) at any time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asad, please try this. The code will write the total sum in the sheet number 1.

```
Sub SheetsSum()
Dim ws              As Worksheet
Dim X               As Double
Dim arrTotalSum()   As Variant

With ThisWorkbook
 'First Calculate the different Sums.
    X = 1
    For Each ws In .Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "coverletter" Then
          'The idea is to prepare an Array and store the summed values.
            ReDim Preserve arrTotalSum(1 To 2, 1 To X)
            arrTotalSum(1, X) = "Total of Sheet " & ws.Name
            arrTotalSum(2, X) = Application.WorksheetFunction.sum(ws.Range("C5:D14"))
            X = X + 1
        End If
    Next ws
  'To write the values, we need to Transpose the Array, from columns to rows.
    .Sheets(1).Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arrTotalSum, 2), UBound(arrTotalSum, 1)).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrTotalSum)
End With

End Sub
```

Also, do not name subs or function with similar name of actual excel vba function.

Comment: Okay I'm Checking

Comment: This code is given the amount but Its given the all sheet amount total in A1 cell 
I'm asking that all sheets total amount like ( sheet 1 total amount is =10 / sheet 2 total amount is = 20 ) but the result of the code have to show in master sheet in separate cell like A1 cell / A2 cell / so on if there are multiply sheet total amount

Comment: I edit the answer and the code delivers a summary in the main sheet.  I hope that is a good approximation.

Comment: okay i'm checking

Comment: error coming in `.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arrTotalSum, 2), UBound(arrTotalSum, 1)).Value = Application.worhsheetfunction.Transpose(arrTotalSum)`

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, check "worhsheetfunction" is "WorkSheet"

Comment: You can avoid `Application.Transpose`: Use `Redim arrTotalSum(1 To .Worksheets.Count, 1 To 2)` before the loop. Remove `X = 1`. Move `X = X + 1` to right below `If ws.Name ...`. Remove your `ReDim...`. Switch the rows and columns getting `arrTotalSum(X, 1)` and `arrTotalSum(X, 2)`. Change the last line to `.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Resize(X, 2).Value = arrTotalSum`. Obviously, the trick is in using `X` instead of `UBound(arrTotalSum, 1)` to return only the `X` number of rows of the too big array. Of course in this particular case, the exact size (number of rows) is `.Worksheets.Count - 1`.

Comment: If the workbook contains any charts, the line `For Each ws In .Sheets` will fail since `ws` is declared as a worksheet so you should loop over the worksheets collection instead: `For Each ws in .Worksheets`.

Answer (score 0):

### Sum Up the Values of a Range

- In VBA, both flavors of `Sum` will fail if there are error values in the range:

  - The early-bound `WorksheetFunction.Sum`, short for `Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum`, will raise an error.
  - The late-bound `Application.Sum` will return an error value.
- You can use the `NumRangeSum` function to always get the sum of a range (even if it is non-contiguous).

```vb
Sub UpdateSums()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("CoverLetter")
    Dim sCell As Range: Set sCell = sws.Range("A1") ' first source cell
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet
    Dim rSum As Variant ' for the procedure not to fail if error values
    ' If you use the function then you can safely use the correct:
    'Dim rSum As Double
    ' The same goes for if you are sure there are no error values.
    
    For Each dws In wb.Worksheets
        If Not dws Is sws Then ' is not the source worksheet
            ' This will result in an error value if there is an error value
            ' in the range.
            rSum = Application.Sum(dws.Range("C5:D14"))
            ' To prevent this, you can instead use the function:
            'rSum = NumRangeSum(dws.Range("C5:D14"))
            dws.Range("H4").Value = rSum
            sCell.Value = rSum
            Set sCell = sCell.Offset(1) ' next source cell below
        'Else ' is the source worksheet; do nothing
        End If
    Next dws
    
    MsgBox "Sums updated.", vbInformation

End Sub


Function NumRangeSum(ByVal mrg As Range) As Double

    Dim mrSum As Variant: mrSum = Application.Sum(mrg)
    
    Dim tSum As Double
    
    If IsNumeric(mrSum) Then ' is a number
        tSum = CDbl(mrSum)
    Else ' is an error value
        
        Dim arg As Range
        Dim aData() As Variant, aValue As Variant
        Dim ar As Long, arCount As Long, ac As Long, acCount As Long
        
        For Each arg In mrg.Areas
            aValue = Application.Sum(arg)
            If IsNumeric(aValue) Then ' is a number
                tSum = tSum + CDbl(aValue)
            Else ' is an error value
                arCount = arg.Rows.Count
                acCount = arg.Columns.Count
                If arCount * acCount = 1 Then ' one cell
                    ReDim aData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): aData(1, 1) = arg.Value
                Else ' multiple cells
                    aData = arg.Value
                End If
                For ar = 1 To arCount
                    For ac = 1 To acCount
                        aValue = aData(ar, ac)
                        If VarType(aValue) = vbDouble Then ' is a number
                            tSum = tSum + CDbl(aValue)
                        'Else ' is not a number; do nothing
                        End If
                    Next ac
                Next ar
            End If
        Next arg
    
    End If
    
    NumRangeSum = tSum

End Function
```

Comment: getting error at `Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("CoverLetter")`

Comment: I guess the workbook containing this code is different from the workbook containing the `CoverLetter` worksheet. Are you using `Personal.xlsb`? Please do clarify. Possibly, you could replace `ThisWorkbook` with `ActiveWorkbook` (not recommended), or better with e.g. `Workbooks("SomeWorkbook.xlsx")`.